# SAS Studio seems to imply that apparently non-normal data is normal

Tags: statistics, sas, goodness-of-fit, normal

I have some data I'm trying to analyze in SAS Studio (university edition). I am using the Distribution Analysis feature to try to test some data for normality.

It gives me the following histogram:

[image]

Skewness is approximately 2.934 and Kurtosis is approximately 9.013. I would have assumed based on that (and the fact that the shape of the histogram looks so different than the normal curve) that this is *not* normally distributed. However, my goodness-of-fit tests are:

[image]

The Kolmogorov-Smirnov D Statistic is 0.2820865, PR > d < 0.010.

The Cramer-von Mises W-Sq statistic is 2.5706303 with Pr > W-Sq <0.005.

The Anderson-Darling A-Sq statistic is 13.2288360 with Pr > A-Sq <0.005.

Unless I'm misreading that horribly, isn't that implying that this is, in fact, normal?

Can someone point out what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mixed up the null and alternative hypotheses.

The null hypotheses are that the data are normally distributed. You get three small p-values that would lead most people to reject the null hypotheses I’m favor of the alternative hypotheses of non-normal distributions.

This is completely consistent with your visual examination and inspection of the skewness and kurtosis values.

Comment: As a tangent, it is poor practice to run a KS test for a parametric distribution by estimating the parameter(s) from the data. That may or may not be what SAS is doing, testing a null of $H_0: X\sim N(\bar{x}, s^2)$.